# Pulseaudio no LFE (subwoofer output) in 2.1 or 4.1 configuration

Tags: pulseaudio

I'm using pulseaudio with a 6-channel USB sound device (which reports itself as a "CM106 Like Sound Device").  I added the following to `~/.config/pulse/daemon.conf`:

```
enable-lfe-remixing = yes
lfe-crossover-freq = 50
```

If I open `pavucontrol` and, under the configuration tab, select "Analog Surround 5.1 Output," everything works fine as best I can tell, except for the fact that I don't have 5 speakers.  (I can test by moving the speakers around to different output ports and playing surround sound test files.)

Unfortunately, if I select either "Analog Surround 4.1 Output" or "Analog Surround 2.1 Output", I get no sound out of my subwoofer.  Is there any way to make my subwoofer work with fewer than 6 channels?

Comment: What version of Pulseaudio are you using? This [1] states, it should work with Pulseaudio 7.0 and later. I have the same trouble as you with an Asus Xonar U7 USB soundcard with Pulseaudio 11.1 on Gentoo Linux. An interesting thing is that I get no subwoofer channel output at all on any of the output jacks.

[1] http://voices.canonical.com/david.henningsson/2015/12/15/2-1-surround-sound-support/

Comment: Using pulseaudio 11 on arch linux.

Answer (score 0):

It is the complete setup.

Copy the daemon.conf file.

```
cp /etc/pulse/daemon.conf ~/.config/pulse/
```

Uncomment 'enable-lfe-remixing' and set yes.

```
enable-lfe-remixing = yes
```

Copy the default.pa file.

```
cp /etc/pulse/default.pa ~/.config/pulse/
```

Add at the end of the file this load module.

```
load-module module-combine channels=6 channel_map=front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right,front-center,lfe
```

Open `alsamixer` > select the sound card which manage the woofer (`F6`) > 
unmute the bass speaker `<Bass Spe>`.

Finally reboot your computer / laptop.

If you are looking for test it. I recommend the [Woofer and Subwoofer Test](http://www.leeenux-linux.com/blog/woofer-and-subwoofer-test/) web page then click on the link '80-89Hz' or any greater than 50Hz.

The original solution: [Andrea Grandi](https://www.andreagrandi.it/2013/06/22/how-to-make-subwoofer-work-in-ubuntu/)

Comment: The problem isn't that the subwoofer doesn't work, as that problem has been fixed.  The problem is that the subwoofer doesn't work in 2.1 or 4.1 mode.  If you can answer the question, please explain how to make a subwoofer work with only 2 or 4 normal speakers instead of 5.  Otherwise, I think you are only explaining how to work around an old bug that has previously been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I know that's an old thread, but I also know that some people like me, still have this problem. I found a solution, a really easy one and it worked great after messing around with the config files.

In /etc/pulse/daemon.conf I commented the following lines :

```
#enable-remixing = yes

#remixing-use-all-sink-channels = yes
 
#remixing-produce-lfe = yes

#remixing-consume-lfe = yes

#lfe-crossover-freq = 80
```

then restart pulseaudio

```
pulseaudio -k
```

This ONLY works if you have a real multichannel sound system (5.1, 4.1, etc.). Upmixing is only a solution for stereo sound systems "fake multichannel" (that's why the lfe doesn't work, at least, for me).

The crossover is useless in a true multichannel system like I use, because the av-receiver already does the job. The only thing pulseaudio does now (in a 5.1 configuration for example), is send the 6 channels to the av-receiver and the av-receiver will do the job perfectly fine and send each channel to the right speaker.

I hope this will help people having this issue.

Comment: I think you are missing the point of the question... It always worked with 5.1 speakers.  The problem was getting it to work with 2.1.

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem ,but I do think it's a driver problem, as Even Testing the output to the subwoofer, it doesn't work. Doing the same test with 5.1 configuration does output the sound to the subwoofer, but without the LFE mix crossover when you play some music, it doesn't output sound to the subwoofer

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna post what has worked for me,

```
cp /etc/pulse/daemon.conf ~/.config/pulse/
```

edit ~/.config/pulse/daemon.conf

find follow lines uncomment and leave as described:

```
 remixing-produce-lfe = yes
 remixing-consume-lfe = yes
 lfe-crossover-freq = 120
 enable-remixing = yes
```

Save it

and issue

```
 pulseaudio -k
```

to restart pulse audio

This worked for me with a 5.1 profile sound, and the Subwoofer is now outputing sound

The **lfe-crossover-freq = 120** is the configuration to set on which frequency
you wish to send the output to the subwoofer

Comment: Yup, and as stated in the question, this always worked.  The problem was only trying for a non-5.1 configuration such as 2.1.